# Doctrine Postgres boolean to string

Tags: php, string, postgresql, doctrine, boolean

I am trying to add Doctrine to an existing PHP application that uses postgres. 
The problem I'm having is Doctrine returns a boolean (0,1) for booleans in the database whereas postgress returns the string 't' or 'f'.

In the application we already have lots of checks for == 't' and =='f' so we don't want to change the code.

Is there anyway to force Doctrine to return the string 't' and 'f'

Thanks

Comment: Also atm I am not using the Doctrine ORM, only the Doctrine DBAL layer

Comment: How will this help as I want to return f and t.
Isn't it doctrine that changes the original f and t to a boolean, so it's a doctrine configuration, not a psql one.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know that a DBAL is what you want if you want the raw values here.  I say this having written a PHP dbal for mysql/postgresql portability back in 1999.  The whole point of a dbal is to ensure portability across databases, and this means that boolean types need to be mapped to true/false values in your language of operation.

My recommendation would be very different, and namely use the DBAL in parts of your code where it works, and start porting other areas to handle boolean values according to basic truth value.  When a section works, move it over.  You can probably do this on a function by function basis if you want.